# Array desde Checkbox Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript

A través de [este ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-example?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) que encontré en internet, quiero almacenar en un array los elementos seleccionados de un **Selection lists** en *Angular Material*

Componente.html

```html
        <mat-card>
      <mat-card-content>
          <mat-selection-list #shoes>
              <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes" [(selected)]="shoe.checked">
                {{shoe.title}}
              </mat-list-option>
            </mat-selection-list>
            <p>
              Options : {{ shoes.selectedOptions.selected.value}}
            </p>

           <pre>{{this.result | json}}</pre>

      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
```

No logro llenar el arrar con las selecciones que hago manualmente dejo [link del proyecto](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-list-option-checked)
componente.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'list-selection-example',
      styleUrls: ['list-selection-example.css'],
      templateUrl: 'list-selection-example.html',
    })
    export class ListSelectionExample implements OnInit {
      typesOfShoes: any[];
      ngOnInit() {
        this.typesOfShoes = [
          {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Aaa',
            checked: true,
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Bbb',
            checked: false,
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            title: 'Ccc',
            checked: true,
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            title: 'Ddd',
            checked: false,
          },
        ];
      }

      get result() {
        return this.typesOfShoes.filter(item => item.checked);
      }
    }
```

Tambien a través de esta opcion imprimirlos directamente desde el html

[image: Dejo imagen de codigo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega un ngModel y un evento ngModelChange `[(ngModel)]="selectedOptions"` en el mat-selection-list

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-list-option-checked-koel6w?file=app/list-selection-example.ts

Comment: El `ngModelChange` no es necesario.